if $\omega(\gamma)=\gamma$, then $\gamma$ is a periodic orbit?
I have the following corollary: 
In the line "$\omega(\gamma)=\gamma$, and $\gamma$ is a periodic orbit" I understand that $\omega(\gamma)=\gamma$ implies $\gamma$ is a periodic orbit. Is this true? I was trying to prove but I couldn't. I take this Corollary from Jack Hale of Ordinary Differential Equations
